# The BSD's stat option equivalent to `%y` in GNU

Tags: bsd, stat

There's an option `%y` which state the last modification time
     %y   time of last data modification, human-readable

BSD's stat could list verbose information as

```
    $ stat -x Foo
      File: "Foo"
      Size: 96           FileType: Directory
      Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (  501/   me)  Gid: (   20/   staff)
    Device: 1,4   Inode: 8605007622    Links: 3
    Access: Thu Apr 12 10:28:45 2018
    Modify: Thu Mar 22 09:44:46 2018
    Change: Thu Mar 22 09:44:46 2018
```

What's the equivalent to `%y` in BSD `stat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an OpenBSD system:

```
$ stat -f '%Sm' myfile
Apr 12 09:40:05 2018
```

The `%Sm` format means "modification time (`m`), as a string (`S`)".

Without the `S`, you'll get a Unix timestamp:

```
$ stat -f '%m' myfile
1523518805
```

These are the equivalents of `%y` and `%Y` with GNU `stat -c "FORMAT"` apart from the slight difference in the `%y` format output.